# Too many joins for cache-building

Tags: c#, nhibernate, caching, fluent-nhibernate

Consider the following method which is used for building a cache of authorization information. When you have a context user the cache will be able to tell you what your rights are for what companies etc.

```
    internal List<UserGroupInfo> BuildUserGroupCache()
    {
        // NB! If you remove the ToArray() a lot of duplicate infos will be generated!
        return Session.Query<UserGroup>()
            .FetchMany(ug => ug.FunctionGroups).ThenFetchMany(fg => fg.Functions)
            .FetchMany(ug => ug.Companies).ToArray().Select(ug => new UserGroupInfo(ug)).ToList();
    }
```

Now, the problem with this is that it generates sql with six joins. Here's my from clause. (You don't need to know what my fields are.)

```
   [UserGroup] usergroup0_
   left outer join FunctionGroupsToUserGroups functiongr1_
     on usergroup0_.Id = functiongr1_.UserGroup_id
   left outer join [FunctionGroup] functiongr2_
     on functiongr1_.FunctionGroup_id = functiongr2_.Id
   left outer join FunctionsToFunctionGroups functions3_
     on functiongr2_.Id = functions3_.FunctionGroup_id
   left outer join [Function] function4_
     on functions3_.Function_id = function4_.Id
   left outer join UserGroupsToCompanies companies5_
     on usergroup0_.Id = companies5_.UserGroup_id
   left outer join [Company] company6_
     on companies5_.Company_id = company6_.Id
```

Why is this a problem? Cause when I have many of each of these entities the result set will quickly grow very large and will contain a lot of unecessarily duplicated data. Hibernating rhinos has this to say on the matter of [too many joins](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/NHProf/learn/alert/TooManyJoins).

The automapping overrides for these are like this:

```
        //UserGroup
        mapping.HasManyToMany(x => x.Companies)
            .FetchType.Select()
            .ExtraLazyLoad();
        mapping.HasManyToMany(x => x.FunctionGroups)
            .FetchType.Select();

        //FunctionGroup
        mapping.HasManyToMany(x => x.Functions)
            .FetchType.Select();
```

How can I change this so that I do not get all of those joins? What I would like to achieve is a full select for each of the Entity types; UserGroup, FunctionGroup and Function, and have NHibernate build up the relationships based on the relationship tables; FunctionGroupToUserGroups etc.

How should I go about doing that, or indeed do it myself through the use of HQL or whatever. I'm pretty much open to any suggestion at this point.